# DP Alt mode USBC stops work working periodically

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, thinkpad, displayport, usb-c

I have Lenovo Thinkpad P1 Gen 3.(Nvidia Quadro graphics and a video output controller.) And a Lenovo 1 wire monitor - USB-C Hub + DP Alt mode.

This setup's video (DP part) randomly stops working and then randomly restarts working. USB hub works without issues.

The same machine will work with same Ubuntu version from USB drive and Windows. Same cable, not even unplugged between restarts.

My installed Ubuntu version doesn't even detect the monitor at startup. While kernel on the installation media does.

My overall question is - what mitigation should I engage in and how should I validate that the next `sudo apt upgrade` doesn't screw up my setup?

What I tried and what didn't work:

- Keeping back kernel versions (still breaks, as it seems that this isn't just a kernel issue)
- Using only Nuveau (crashes as soon as you look at it the wrong way)
- Sticking to Nvidia "open" drivers

Please be realistic in solutions. Don't tell me to "reinstall", because this is happening several times per month and I'm not reinstalling my primary development machine OS multiple times per month.(only OS developers have the luxury of time to do that)

Comment: From your question. My installed Ubuntu version doesn't even detect the monitor at startup. While kernel on the installation media does. What does this mean?

Comment: That my installed version fails to detect the USBC DP Alt mode monitor at startup (before login prompt)... but if I insert the USB with Ubuntu installer, it detects the monitor at boot and shows boot screen.

Comment: And again... Quiet update to Kernel from 5.19.0-31 to 5.19.0-35 screwed the pooch!